# Laravel package session variable not saving with ajax call

Tags: php, laravel, session, package

I'm building a package called `under-construction`. When this package is activated in a config
file the site will be underconstruction only people with the right code can access the 
application.

https://github.com/larsjanssen6/underconstruction

[image]

**The problem that I have right now:**

When the code is entered I make an ajax call that hit's this controller method (called **check**):

https://github.com/larsjanssen6/underconstruction/blob/master/src/Controllers/CodeController.php

If the code is correct a session variable is being set:

```
session(['can_visit' => true]);
```

Then in my **vue.js** code I redirect to `/`. And it will hit my middleware again. Here I check if  a session called `can_visit` exists.

```
return session()->has('can_visit');
```

https://github.com/larsjanssen6/underconstruction/blob/master/src/UnderConstruction.php

But the session variable `can_visit` is always gone! How is that possible?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: check if the middleware "web" is called. its the middleware that initializes the session

Comment: Yes the routes are in web.php so they use the web middleware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not loading the session middleware, so session is not started and no values are persisted.

As was mentioned in the comments, even though your protected routes (`/`) are within the web middleware (read session), your service provider's routes (`/under/construction`, `/under/check`) are not (no write session).

The simple fix is to add the session, or even better, the whole web middleware.

```
$routeConfig = [
    'namespace' => 'LarsJanssen\UnderConstruction\Controllers',
    'prefix' => 'under',
    'middleware' => [
        'web', // add this
        // DebugbarEnabled::class, // leaving this dead code behind despite vcs
    ],
];
```

However, you might quickly run into trouble with infinite redirect loops if a user adds your middleware to their web middleware group. So I would add a check of some sort to make sure you're not on one of the existing `underconstruction` routes.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // check this isn't one of our routes
    // too bad router hasn't loaded named routes at this stage in pipeline yet :(
    // let's hope it doesn't conflict with user's routes
    if ($request->is('under/*')) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    if (! $this->config['enabled']) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    if (!$this->hasAccess($request)) {
        return new RedirectResponse('/under/construction');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

And ultimately guessing from the context of this project, I'd expect most people would want to stick this in the global middleware. However, you're going to run into the same session-hasn't-started-yet issues because that doesn't run in the global middleware. So there's more to chew on. Happy coding!

Comment: thanks a lot for your time. Really appreciate it! Finally have a solution after doing a lot of research.